# Finding file name of test that failed using go test (golang)

Tags: unit-testing, go

When a Go unit test fails "go test" will display a message like:

--- FAIL: TestFillDeepStruct (0.00s)

But what is the name of the file (in this case Deep_test.go) containing the failing test.  I can find no option to "go test" to do this. I have many test files and it is tedious to grep for the test function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-v` (verbose) flag:

```
» go test -v example                                                                                                                                         === RUN   TestReturn
--- FAIL: TestReturn (0.00s)
    ex_test.go:10: /home/user/go/src/example
    ex_test.go:11: Expected 42, got 43
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    example 0.002s
```

In case there are some tests that will not show error line, you may use a this simple bash function:

```
function find_failed_tests(){
    FAIL_FILE="/tmp/failed.tmp"
    go test example | grep "^--- FAIL" | awk '{print $3}' > $FAIL_FILE
    grep -rf $FAIL_FILE  ~/go/src/$1
    rm -rf $FAIL_FILE
}

# Usage:
find_failed_tests example
```

Comment: Except when it doesn't work: `func TestFail(t *testing.T) { t.Fail() }`.

Comment: @peterSO Just added that to my answer.

Comment: The OP already knows about `grep`: "it is tedious to grep for the test function name". He asked for something better.

Comment: Yes, and this solution greps for all failed functions. Also, it won't be tedious to reuse a bash function.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Thanks Syntagma for your reply. I think you are saying (1) use -v, but if that doesn't work (2) the bash function.

Well I already tried -v and that does not give the file name. (Maybe this is because the tests just use t.Fail().)

The bash function looks just what I need (in the absence of any option to go test). I will give it a go.

Thanks again.